# Libgdx UI animation stops when non-continuous rendering. How make it work?

Tags: animation, drop-down-menu, libgdx, render

I am using a SelectBox in libgdx and I want to use non-continuous rendering to
save battery power.

However, the render only triggers on events or on:
`Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();`

But the SelectBox is animated when it drops down, however, the animation will only continue
for as long as I touch the device. This can lead to it stopping halfway animated.

How can I keep rendering for as long as the SelectBox is animating the dropdown menu?

Comment: You might either extend the SelectBox and let it request the rendering itself when it animates itself, or you could maybe detect the touch and then just request a rendering for the next 0.5s.

Comment: I figured something like that, but kindof hoped that there was a better way. It's silly they didn't think of this.